# Missing Image in Notification Emails

Tags: bug

I'm seeing a problem in Outlook with this notification email template (http://screencast.com/t/SK4dFHsKkt) and the broken image.

Outlook freezes up for about a minute or longer while it tries to load the image if Outlook is configured to download email images.

The image never loads because the source or link isn't defined in the email template as you can see here: 
http://screencast.com/t/QB9uNNVOL

Comment: Several folks have written in to indicate this issue in outlook, however it's the only one that blocks images this silently. Are you sure that outlook trusts the sender, and nothing is keeping it from trusting sstatic.net?

Comment: The notification that I received for your comment has the missing image but didn't stall Outlook. Not sure why it did the other day and not today. The code looks the same and I haven't changed anything in my settings. I've never told Outlook to not trust sstatic.net so I can't imagine that is enabled... I looked in the Trust Center and I don't see anything obvious. All images are set to download for all senders. If it helps, this is an imap account.

Comment: I reproduced this in gmail, finally - some stray parts of the site URL get tacked on to the image `href` tag, but I can't seem to figure out what makes that happen. I alerted the devs to it - should be fixed as soon as _they_ can reproduce it

Comment: Let me know if you need any troubleshooting on my end. Happy to help. Note I haven't had the issue with Outlook since I posted this. Isn't that always the case!